# Casting object to generic IEnumerable with only type available

Tags: c#, .net, generics, casting

What is the correct code to cast an object back to a generic list like so?

```
Type x = typeof(MyClass);
object o = new List<MyClass>();

List<x> l = o as List<x>; // Not working
```

EDIT:
Maybe it wasn't all clear: The object is a list of a generic type which i don't know at compile time.. nevertheless List has functions like "Add" i can call anyway, like:

```
l.Add((new MyClass() as object)) as x);
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using `List<x>` instead of List<MyClass> on the last line?  Is the requirement to cast the list to a generic list given a Type object?

Comment: In short, you can't use this kind of syntax.  Perhaps you could explain why you need this, and someone could suggest a better alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List<MyClass> l = (List<MyClass>)o;
```

or

```
List<MyClass> l = o as List<MyClass>;
```

---

Do you mean

```
List<> l = o as List<>;
```

This is not possible until you use a generic class:

```
class C<T>
{
    public List<T> List = new List<T>();
}
```

Usage:

```
C<MyClass> c = new C<MyClass>();
c.List.Add(new MyClass());
```

---

Finally I got OP's goal:

```
Type listType = typeof(List<>);
Type targetType = listType.MakeGenericType(typeof(YourClass));
List<YourClass> list = (List<YourClass>)Activator.CreateInstance(targetType);
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.makegenerictype.aspx) for details.

Comment: Thx. But how can I use "var c = new C<typeFromRuntime>();"?

Comment: Thx :) But i don't want a new instance of my type but rather use the type to cast object o to List<>, so i can call Add on it

Comment: @David: so you wan to to cast programmatically to type known only in runtime?

Answer (score 1):

When the generic interface is not usable because you don't know the type arguments at compile time, but a non-generic interface is available, you can use that instead:

```
Type x = typeof(MyClass);
object o = new List<MyClass>();

IList l = (IList)o;
l.Add(new MyClass());
```

The non-generic `IList` interface is implemented by the generic `List<T>` class.

Answer (score 0):

```
object testobject = new List<string>();
List<string> list = (List<string>)testobject;
```

Comment: You downvote answers because the poster changed the question after I posted my answer...?

Answer (score 0):

```
        List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee> { new Employee { Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Name = "SOME" }, new Employee { Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Name = "SOME2" } };

        object obj = employees;

        List<Employee> unBoxed = (List<Employee>)obj;
```